# A big veebar - how to produce it?

Tags: symbols, logic, underline

guys.

I'm writing some logic equations and I need something like this:

[image: "Big veebar"]

I produce this symbol through the following piece of code:

`\begin{equation} \underline{\bigvee^{\forall R_{I}}}R_{I}(x,y) \end{equation}`

However, when I have wider limits, this ugly thing happens:

[image]

The question is: is there any way to produce a "big" `\veebar` symbol where the underbar has the same length of the "V" (more likely the first picture)?

Any ideas are welcomed! 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! Just declare a new math operator that can have limits. This can be done with the starred version of `\DeclareMathOperator`, `\DeclareMathOperator*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\ubigvee}{\underline{\bigvee}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} 
\ubigvee^{\forall R_{I}}R_{I}(x,y) \quad
\ubigvee^{\forall R_{I},x,y}R_{I}(x,y) 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works like a charm! Thank you very much! :)